# How to select on field value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

What want to achieve is something like the following: select `a.column1` as value x if `a.column1` has a value otherwise I want `b.column1` as value x.

I would imagine something like the following pseudocode:

```
SELECT (hasValue(a.column1)?a.column1:b.column1 as x FROM a, b
```

In my real situation it is actually three tables. I guess that could make the effort a bit more tricker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coalesce returns the first non-null value, try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.column1,b.column1) as x FROM a,b;
```

Comment: +1 Code can be formatted as code by highlighting it and pressing the `{}` button - I have formatted your query like so.